# React with render props - component not updating on props change

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management

Imagine you are using [containment](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment), but suddenly you need your intermediate component to interact with the child it contain.

In react doc they say:

> You can take it even further with render props if the child needs to communicate with the parent before rendering.

[source](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#before-you-use-context)

---

**This is my case, I need both `Top` and `Intermediate` components to control (different) props of `Bottom` component.**

Knowing that `Top` contain `Intermediate` component that contain `Bottom` component (html hierarchy).

---

**Here is something to play with (press the buttons):** https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-props-not-rendering-issue?file=src/App.js

Equivalent in typescript:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

export function Top() {
  const [a, sA] = useState(false);

  function renderBottom(b: boolean) {
    return (
        <Bottom a={a} b={b}/>
    );
  }

  return (
      <div>
        <div>A in TOP: {a ? 'true' : 'false'}</div>
        <button onClick={e => sA(!a)}>A</button>
        <Intermediate renderBottom={renderBottom}/>
      </div>
  );
}

export function Intermediate(p: {renderBottom: any}) {
  const [b, sB] = useState(false);

  const BottomComponentWithASet = p.renderBottom;

  return (
      <div style={{background: 'red'}}>
        <div>B in Intermediate: {b ? 'true' : 'false'}</div>
        <button onClick={e => sB(!b)}>B</button>
        <BottomComponentWithASet b={b}/>
      </div>
  );
}

export function Bottom(p: {a: boolean; b: boolean; }) {
  console.log(p.b); // is correct, start false, change to true on click
  return (
      <div>
        <div>A: {p.a ? 'true' : 'false'}</div>
        {/* this one bellow will alway stay true */}
        <div>B: {p.b ? 'true' : 'false'}</div>
      </div>
  );
}
```

I know I could have the state of `b` and `a` being handled into `Top` component. I have started with that, but it force me to put a lot of code into `Top` component, that is related to `Intermediate` component.

This is what I have been using before, it work. BUT, it put a lot of code into the `Top` component, that is related to `Intermediate` component (example here is just a simple representation).

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

export function Top() {
  const [a, sA] = useState(false);
  
  // oh no, we are handling something that is related to `Intermediate` and `Bottom` component only !
  const [b, sB] = useState(false);

  return (
      <div>
        <div>A in TOP: {a ? 'true' : 'false'}</div>
        <button onClick={e => sA(!a)}>A</button>
        <Intermediate>
          <div>B in Intermediate: {b ? 'true' : 'false'}</div>
          <button onClick={e => sB(!b)}>B</button>
          <Bottom a={a} b={b}/>
        </Intermediate>
      </div>
  );
}

export function Intermediate(p: any) {
  return (
      <div style={{background: 'red'}}>
        { p.children }
      </div>
  );
}

export function Bottom(p: {a: boolean; b: boolean; }) {
  console.log(p.b);
  return (
      <div>
        <div>A: {p.a ? 'true' : 'false'}</div>
        <div>B: {p.b ? 'true' : 'false'}</div>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, seem like just posting it on stackoverflow, is helping me find what is wrong in my code. By re-reading [Render Props doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html), I realised I have replaced a function by a component. This code bellow made it work.

```
export function Intermediate(p: {renderBottom: any}) {
  const [b, sB] = useState(false);

  return (
      <div style={{background: 'red'}}>
        <div>B in Intermediate: {b ? 'true' : 'false'}</div>
        <button onClick={e => sB(!b)}>B</button>
        {p.renderBottom(b)}
      </div>
  );
}
```

It remind me of days when class keyword did not exist in javascript, and we used function instead to declare them. Maybe one day we will have a `component` keyword, so that we do not confuse function with components like I did.